# MySQL math on text in select list should fail

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

How can I make MySQL throw an error (not simply issue a warning) when I try and perform a mathematical operation with text in the SELECT list. For example:

```
SELECT 'foo' * 'bar';
```

I want that query to fail.

Comment: What’s the difference you are expecting to see if this returns a warning or an error? Are you running this somewhere other than a UI where the calling process needs to be able to identify that the statement errored?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `multiply`(a float, b float) RETURNS float
    NO SQL
BEGIN
RETURN a*b;
END
```

Then `select multiply('foo','bar');` will return an error, while `select multiply(2,3);` still returns the correct answer.

But the downside is that you need to use this function in stead of the normal way of multiplying.

Answer (score 0):

For data altering statements (INSERT/UPDATE/etc), these types of operations will already produce an error, assuming you have the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES sql_mode enabled, which has been the default since mariadb 10.2.4 and mysql 5.7.5.

For non-data altering statements, have your client check if there was a warning; details depend on what client you are using.